# FPDF cell no rellena con color y mete un salto de linea que no quiero

Tags: php, fpdf

Buenas tardes a todos!

Soy novato con FPDF y se me nota mucho, tengo un problema con cell y es que no me está **rellenando** la celda como yo quiero y ademas me mete un **salto de línea** (en un multicell que va justo debajo) que no quiero, ¿me podéis ayudar?

```
pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY());          
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);  
$pdf->SetFillColor(111,222,255); 
$pdf->Cell(20, 0, 'Orden', 1, 1, 'L', True); 
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX()+20,$pdf->GetY());      
$pdf->Cell(20,0,'2',1,1,'L',True);  
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX()+40,$pdf->GetY()); 
$pdf->Cell(20,0,'Tono',0,1,'L',True);  
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX()+60,$pdf->GetY()); 
$pdf->SetFillColor(0,0,255);
$pdf->Cell(22,0,'',0,1,'L',True);  
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX()+82,$pdf->GetY()); 
$pdf->Cell(20,0,'Gama',0,1,'L',True);  
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX()+102,$pdf->GetY()); 
$pdf->SetFillColor(0,0,255);
$pdf->Cell(20,0,'',0,1,'L',True);

$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY()+3);  
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 
$pdf->SetWidths(array(124));
$pdf->RowOscuro(array(utf8_decode("DESCRIPCIÓN")));
```

funcion RowOscuro:

```
    function RowOscuro($data)
{
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=8*$nb;
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        $this->SetFillColor(122,196,117); //relleno
        $this->SetDrawColor(255,255,255); //borde
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //letra
        $this->MultiCell($w,8,$data[$i],1,$a,'true');
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    $this->Ln($h);
}
```

La idea es que salieran 6 celdas, de izquierda a derecha serían:

**| Orden | 2 | Tono | celda sin texto rellena de azul | Gama | celda sin texto rellena de azul |**

Comment: En tu código no se ve ningún [`MultiCell`](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/multicell.htm). Por defecto todos los `MultiCell` realizan un salto de línea y no se puede evitar, por lo que es necesario manipular el `X` e `Y` para manejarlo.

Comment: @Marcos edito y pongo el multicell de debajo, es que esta en una función, mi mayor problema es que cell no me rellena la celda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas pasando mal los parámetros al método `Cell`; estos son:

> Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])

Donde:

> **`w`**: Ancho de celdas. Si 0, estos se extienden hasta l márgen derecha de la página.
>   **`h`**: Alto de las celdas.
>   **`txt`**: Cadena para imprimir.
>   `ln`: Indica donde la posición actual debería ir antes de invocar. Los valores posibles son: `0` (a la derecha), `1`(al comienzo de la siguiente línea) o `2` debajo.
>   **`border`** Indica si los bordes deben ser dibujados al rededor del bloque la celda. El valor puede ser un número:  `0` (no borde), `1` (marco)
>   o una cadena conteniendo algún o todos los siguientes carácteres (en cualquier orden): `L`(izquierda), `T`(superior) `R`(derecha) o `B`(inferior).
>   Valor por defecto: 0.
>   **`align`**:  Establece la alineación de texto. Los posibles valores son:
>   `L` (alineación a la izquierda), `C`(centrado), `R`(alineación a la derecha) o `J`(justificación). Valor por defecto `J`.
>   **`fill`**: Indica si el fondo de la celda debe ser dibujado (`true`) o transparente (`false`). Valor por defecto: `false`.
>   **`link`**: URL o identificador retornado por AddLink().

### Solución:

- Debes indicar el alto de la celda (`h`), de lo contrarior solo se vera una línea finita.
- Si indicas la posición donde deberia ir (`ln`) igual a cero (`0`), te puedes ahorrar tener que manipular el `xy`.

#### Código:

```
$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY()); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetFillColor(111, 222, 255);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Orden', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, '2', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Tono', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 255);
$pdf->Cell(22, 10, '', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Gama', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 255);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, '', 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->Ln(3);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 
$pdf->SetWidths(array(124));
$pdf->RowOscuro(array(utf8_decode("DESCRIPCIÓN")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo relleno una celda de esta manera:

```
 $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DE LA DEPENDENCIA', 1,1,'C',$fill);
```

Pero si es para una cabecera de una tabla se puede construir así,  basado en documentación del foro de soporte y ejemplos de FPDF:

```html
 // Cabecera
        $w = array(6, 29, 17, 15, 58, 38, 30, 20, 25, 25, 18);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
            $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[$i]), 6, utf8_decode($header[$i]), 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Ln();
        //Restauración de colores y fuentes
        $this->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetDrawColor(6, 16, 59);
        $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
        $this->SetFont('');
        // Datos
        $fill = true;
```

donde el header de la cabecera se define de esta manera desde otro archivo que llama a la clase del PDF.

```html
// Títulos de las columnas
            $header = array('No.', 'MUNICIPIO', 'NUMERO_ACTIVO', 'SUBNUMERO', 'DESCRIPCIÓN DEL BIEN', 'MATERIAL', 'COLOR', 'MARCA', 'MODELO', 'SERIE', 'ESTADO DEL BIEN');
            // Carga de la tabla
            $pdf->ActivosTable($header);
```

y esta seria la forma en que se aprecia la salida de la cabecera de la tabla en color azul

[image: vista de la cabecera de una tabla con fpdf]

Existen mucha mas formas, pero esta es la que a mi me pareció útil.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado así:

```
pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY());          
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);  
$pdf->SetFillColor(111,222,255); 
$pdf->Cell(20, 8, 'Orden', 1, 1, 'L', 'true'); // Si en el segundo parámetro pones 0 te coge el alto de la fila como 0, leugo en vez de True, he puesto 'true'
...

$pdf->SetXY($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY());  // El GetY()+3 metía el salto de línea
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 

$pdf->SetWidths(array(124));
$pdf->RowOscuro(array(utf8_decode("DESCRIPCIÓN")));
```